# Unhandled exception stop all threads in winform app?

Tags: multithreading, winforms, watchdog

I have a multi-threa winform app, in one thread i want to implement a heart beating through socket, this thread send heart beat to a watchdog app. if the winform app run into any unhandled exception, a dialog box pops up by the OS.

My question is will the heart beating thread be stopped as well? so that my watchdog app will detect that heart beating is stopped? is this the right way to implement a watchdog?

Answer (score 0):

You can register for the [unhandled exception event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and use that to report to your watchdog app. It can either set a flag for the heartbeat thread to check, or send a message directly to the watchdog app.